# Use class from CommonJS module in Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, commonjs

I have an npm package with a file similar to this:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = class TModel {
  constructor (app) {
    this.app = app
  }

  static schema () {

  }
}
```

Which I want to use in a Typescript file like so:

```
import Model from 't-model';

export class Book extends Model {
    static schema() : any {
        return {
            title: {
                type: 'string'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. PHPStorm gives the error:

> Cannot resolve file

And compiling with tsc gives me the error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 't-model'

If use `'t-model/index'` instead of `'t-model'` PHPStorm stops giving me an error but tsc still gives the same error.

I am trying to unify packages I would make for the backend API and the frontend, which uses Typescript. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could add what does not work. Are you getting an error... what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have an npm package with a file similar to this:

## If this file is typescript

instead of:

```
module.exports = class TModel {
```

Do `export class TModel` and let TypeScript generate the `module.exports` (compile with `module: commonjs`). This way TypeScript understands the exports

More on this : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

## If the file is javascript

You need to *declare* it:

```
declare module 't-model' {
   class TModel // .....
   export = TModel;
}
```

More on this : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: It is an npm package so I do not have control of the source code. Do I have to fork every npm package I want to use in a Typescript project?

Comment: You. You just need to *declare* the types. For example check out popular project definitions in https://gitter.im/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: So I set up a .d.ts file but I keep getting the error `error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.` no matter what I do.

Comment: Given the TModel class module above, what would be your declaration? I would look at DefinitelyTyped but I don't know any library that exports a class.

Comment: @BeaverusIV you would use `export =`. I've updated the answer as well