# What is best aproach to migrate "module.exports" js file to .ts

Tags: typescript

I saw many examples how to migrate .js to .ts but I still don't knopw what is best aproach to migrate module.

Example:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = class Ticker {
  private time: any;

  constructor(lookbacks) {
    this.time = lookbacks;
  }
};
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean, "best"? You have to change your file to use TypeScript semantics. See [Use class from CommonJS module in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35119668/215552). [The TypeScript site also has plenty of information.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#exporting-from-modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to move things to [ES Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

There's no fun way to automatically move everything, but lucky for you, TypeScript supports the old `module.exports =` syntax as well, so you can migrate at your leisure.

The main points of ES Modules:

```
// a.js

module.exports = class Foo {}

// b.js
module.exports.one = 1;
module.exports.two = true;
module.exports.three = function three() {};
module.exports.four = class Four {};

// c.js
const Foo = require('./a');
const { one, two, three, four } = require('./b');
// or 
// const bModule = require('./b');
// bModule.three();
```

Becomes

```
// a.ts
export default class Foo {}

// b.ts
export const one = 1;
export const two = true;
export function three() {};
export class Four {}

// c.ts
import Foo from './a';
import { one, two, three, four } from './b';
// or
// import * as bModule from './b';
// bModule.three();
```

#### Things to know:

- TypeScript has its own module and exports system from before the ECMAScript specs had one (`export = something` and `import x = require()`), you should not use them in new projects.
- TypeScript has a concept of "namespace" to support the old patterns of using IIFEs and named objects to emulate modules, you should not use them in new projects.
- `module.exports = whatever` and `export default whatever` are not strictly equivalent, you have to refactor all of the `module.exports` as well as the corresponding `require()` calls.